# angular directive to convert ASCII or html codes in special characters in a textbox or text area

Tags: angularjs, textbox, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-value, ng-filter

Here is the challenge I am facing with angularJS text boxes. I want to auto convert all the HTML codes and HTML Name into special characters inside a text-box.

Suppose, {$sce.trustAsHtml('Tom & Jerry');}  it should auto convert into "Tom & Jerry" inside the same text box.
[fiddle example][1]

I tried using custom directives, $sce , ng-model-options but not able to get the required result. Hope you guys can help me out with it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: question is not allowing me to enter the code find the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L5jccw37/) to understand the problem.

Comment: Clarify your question please..

Comment: I am using a service which gives me the data where special characters are in ASCII, HTML codes or HTML Names.(http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm ). But I want to display those in special characters in the textbox not as html codes or ASCII codes .

Comment: just want to understand, how can I use unescape, $sanitize vs $sce in angularjs textbox. Before passing or while entering in textbox I just want to convert all HTML codes into special characters

Answer (score -1):

I just solved it .Try entering any special characters, ASCII codes or html codes in the text box.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
```

{{value}}

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pywk7a9t/)

Comment: Here is an example when you type ' &#38; ' into the text box it will automatically convert into '&' .